# Rails Unknown format error (both HTML and JS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently using Rails 4 and I have 3 controllers that do the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

Two of them currently work just fine, but the third controller complains that ActionController::UnknownFormat in ArticlesController#drafts.  Here is the problematic controller:

```
def drafts
  @user = current_user
  @drafts = @user.articles.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5).draft_and_in_order
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

where the other two controller's actions containing the format snippet look similar.  They all also use the same ajax call, so it probably isn't that, and the call is just a simple default ajax call to the current page (e.g.)

```
$.ajax({ });
```

And triggering the articles#drafts action looks to be good in my rails server as it issues a correct GET response.  The only difference here that I thought might be the case is articles#drafts have a before_actions before it:

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create, :update, :destroy, :drafts]
before_action :correct_user_format, only: [:new, :drafts]
```

since they contain some redirect_to's:

```
 def correct_user_format
   user = User.find_by(id: params[:format])
   unless current_user?(user)
     redirect_to root_url
   end
 end

 def logged_in_user
     unless logged_in?
     flash[:danger] = "Please log in"
     redirect_to root_url
   end
 end
```

Alas, deleting these and the before_actions run into the same error.  And in fact, if I were to only do:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

or

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

I still run into the unknown format issue.  All the controllers are subclasses of ApplicationController, and my corresponding .js.erb is put into app/views/articles/drafts.js.erb.  So I'm not quite sure where or what could be causing rails to throw that error.  The first few lines of my stack trace:

```
actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:230:in `respond_to'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.beta4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
```

Comment: Try changing your parameter name used in `user = User.find_by(id: params[:format])` to another name. Possibly there's a problem with Rails parsing request format.

Comment: Ahh, ok that fixed it: I didn't know the .:format in routes was referring to the actual format of the page as opposed to just an extra parameter.  Refactor time. Thanks!

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, please mark it as an answer so that other people will see what they're missing if somebody googles that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your parameter name used in `user = User.find_by(id: params[:format])` to another name. There should be a problem with Rails parsing request format.