# respond_to js "unknown format"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have this action in my PagesController:

```
def webhook
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I get an error `ActionController::UnknownFormat` when trying to access /webhook.

I have a webhook.js.erb file in my PagesController, and a route associated:
`get '/webhook', to: 'pages#webhook'`

I checked these posts: [Unknown format in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590408/unknown-format-in-rails-4) and [Rails Unknown format error (both HTML and JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712859/rails-unknown-format-error-both-html-and-js) but none had a working answer.

But
I used this syntax previously and it worked so I have no idea what's going on.

How could I fix this ?

EDIT:
Now, I've added `:format => :js` to my link_to, and when I click, the browser displays the js file webhook.js.erb
Here is my link_to:

```
 <%= j link_to "Category", webhook_path(:format => :js), method: :post %>
```

I just have this in my webhook.js.erb to test it:

```
alert("h");
```

What I expect is that when I click on my link, an alert shows up on the page

Comment: are you passing `format: :js` ?

Comment: Could you check if the file webhook.js.erb is in app/views/pages please ?

Comment: i think you are not calling js call, it is due to html call. can you share code how you are calling this action ?

Comment: @dkp I tried:   respond_to do |format|
      format: :js
    end
but I get this error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end

Comment: @Pholochtairze it is

Comment: @z.shan I just have this action, am I supposed to be able to access the page /webhook in my browser or should it only work with get/post requests ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick how you are hitting this action ? there must be form `link_to` or something in your view where you have mentioned the path to this action. There you need to pass `format: :js`. It would be better if you could show your view code and server log.

Comment: @dkp you're right I had to specify it in my link_to, but now it renders the js file, but doesn't execute it. How can I have it executed and not displayed ? Here is my link_to: 
<%= j link_to "Category", favorite_category_path(:id => category.id, :format => :js), method: :post %>

Comment: @GrahamSlick please show your js file .

Comment: @dkp I've edited my post

Comment: try  this one  <%= j link_to "Category", favorite_category_path(:id => category.id), method: :post, remote: true %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= j link_to "Category", favorite_category_path(id: category.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

And your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `remote: true` in your `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Category", favorite_category_path(:id => category.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but I still have an issue with the file being displayed instead of executed. I've edited my post

Comment: @GrahamSlick are you getting any error in your log ?

Comment: I get this :
Rendered categories/webhook.js.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 118ms (Views: 25.5ms | ActiveRecord: 24.2ms)

Which is indeed the file I want, but I want it to be executed not rendered

Comment: @GrahamSlick check my updated answer, you just need to add `remote: true` to make an ajax request which would execute your `js`. And, you do not need to `escape_javascript` or `j` before `link_to`.