# ActionController:UnknownFormat respond_to do |format|

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, formatting

I'm trying to sign up Users using Devise, and render a JS file if a certain parameter is included in the sign-up. I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in RegistrationsController#create
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

This is my "create" action (I marked the line the error pointed to):

```
if resource.persisted?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    if !params[:name].nil?
      View.create(name: params[:name])
      respond_to do |format| #THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    end
  else
    respond_with resource, location: inactive_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  respond_with resource
end
```

The action is "create", in `app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`. The JS file I'm trying to render is `app/views/devise/registrations/create.js.erb`.

My suspicion is that there's a problem with finding the file, but I can't figure out how to point it to the right route, or if that's even the right problem. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Check this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590757/respond-to-js-unknown-format).

Comment: Have you verified that the request is getting sent as JS ?