# Rails Remote True Ajax ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a mini-update method in my model that only updates one field, set up in a chart (so I see the form for each row).  It works properly, but want it to update using AJAX to be able to do multiple updates quickly without waiting for a full page reload.

The cell looks like this:

```
      <td style="min-width: 150px" id="goody_cell<%= blog.id %>">
        <%= render partial: "admin/goody_cell", locals: { blog: blog } %>
      </td>
```

With this as the partial:

```
<% if blog.variation_id %>
  <%= Variation.find(blog.variation_id).name %>
<% end %>

<%= simple_form_for(blog, url: update_goody_path(blog), remote: true, method: :patch, authenticity_token: true) do |f| %>
  <% variation_collection = [] %>
  <% Variation.all.each do |lm| %>
    <% variation_collection << ["#{lm.name}", "#{lm.id}"] %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="row text-left">
    <div class="form-group col-12 mb-0 pb-0">
      <%= f.input :variation_id, label: false, prompt: "Choose a Related Goody", input_html: { id: "lmFor" + blog.id.to_s, class: 'browser-default', onchange: "this.form.submit();" }, collection: variation_collection, required: false %>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- row -->
<% end %>
```

My `blogs/update_goody.js.erb` looks like this:

```
$('#goody_cell<%= blog.id %>').html('<%= j render partial: "admin/goody_cell", locals: { blog: @blog } %>');
```

And my controller method is like this:

```
  def update_goody
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.update!(blog_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

I have the route like this:

```
patch "blogs/:id/update_goody" => "blogs#update_goody", as: "update_goody"
```

When I try to update it, it does update the value, but before it renders the partial, I get an error saying:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:178:in `update_goody'
```

I've looked at SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590757/respond-to-js-unknown-format) but they all say that the error was fixed by adding `remote: true`, which I already have.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Comment: isnt it update_goody.js sould be a update_goody.js.erb ?

Comment: @roshiend Yes, it totally should.  Unfortunately, this doesn't change the error I'm getting.

Comment: what your log says? try add format.html before format.js

Comment: @roshiend It just says `BlogsController#update_goody is missing a template for this request format and variant.` if I do `format.html` before `format.js` (or after, for that matter).

Comment: looks like you are missing update_goody .html.erb file in views blogs

Comment: @roshiend What would go on it? I want it to stay on the same page. Isn't that the point of Ajax?

Comment: When you are defined a controller action you should always have a spefic views for that action. in your case you, should have views/blogs/update_goody .html.erb .Rails initially look for that views when update_goody action triggered. you havent have update_goody.html.erb, thats why you are getting " missing a template" error. by setting respond_to |format| in your action you are telling controller to respond  requests to js instead of html. by doing that so, it will override your update_goody.html.erb file and ignore html.erb file. but you should have update_goody.html.erb in views/bogs folder

Comment: as you have set remote true in your form, rails knows you are looking for ajax request. in controller you are point to respond that request with js (respond_to |format|). if you remove remote true page will redirect to diffrent page that you set in your controller action (i.e respond_to do |format| format.html{redirect_to root_path })

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @ricks Not yet, no.  It still "works" (if you refresh it manually) but no actual fix.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `remote: true`, use `local: false` (Rails 6)

Comment: This did the trick for Rails 6, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have both `update_goody.html.erb` and `update_goody.js.erb` in your `views/blogs` folder.

you dont have to add anything to `update_goody.html.erb` as its not rendering at all.
in your controller

```
def update_goody
    @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if @blog.update!(blog_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @blog.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

note that `format.html` in `respond_to` block. it dosent matter you add it or not as you are set `remote: true` in your form

refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6eE-nd3ci4)

Comment: This didn't throw an error, but it redirected me to the blank HTML page.

Comment: Nope.  `respond_to do |format|
        format
        format.js do
          @blog = Blog.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end` gives me the same `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.

Comment: I haven't use simple form before but i think your remote true is not place right in the form.Take out remote true out of parentheses and place them like `<%=simple_form_for(blog, url: update_goody_path(blog), method: :patch, authenticity_token: true), remote: true do%>`this

Comment: The syntax you suggested yields an unacceptable formatting error.  I tried without parentheses entirely `<%= simple_form_for blog, url: update_goody_path(blog), method: :patch, authenticity_token: true, remote: true do |f| %>` but that just had the same `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.

Comment: `<%=simple_form_for @blog, :url => {:controller => 'blogs', :action => 'update_goody', :method => patch,:authenticity_token => true,:remote => true }  do |f|%>`

Comment: It's now not even recognizing the route.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to put `redirect_to` to render html

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js 
  format.html { redirect_to update_goody_path }
end
```